# Git bash cloning errors

Tags: bash, github

I have installed GitHub and I am trying to clone my account, but I get this error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mutende/testMyGit.git
  Cloning into 'testMyGit'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mutende/testMyGit.git/': Could not resolve proxy: http
```

I have configured the proxy in git bash and when I run the command:

```
$ git config --global --get https.proxy
```

I get this result:

```
https//172.16.63.3:3128
```

But still I can not clone.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your proxy configuration. Add a colon.

```
https://172.16.63.3:3128
```